# How to get commits from another repo, when mine lost history?

Tags: git

There was an **OriginalRepo**, with a commit history like this:

`A -- B -- C`

**MyRepo** was originally a fork of it. However, at some point, MyRepo was migrated and all the commit hashes were changed. So it became something like this:

`A# -- B# -- C#`

Development continued on both repos independently, so now they look something like this:

OriginalRepo: `A  -- B --  C  -- D`

MyRepo:     `A# -- B# -- C# -- X`

**Question**

What would be the best way to get "D" into MyRepo, without losing history or "X"?
(assume that both "X" and "D" are actually a range of commits, and contain merge commits as well)

I tried `git cherry-pick FirstCommitInD^..LastCommitInD -m 1 HEAD`, but when it gets to a merge commit it seems to be getting all the changes from A to D (probably because of the changed commit hashes).

Comment: You could try to run `git rebase original-repo` on your fork and test if that works (and does not contain duplicate commits). However, this will require you to do a force push if you want to update your fork with that.

Comment: Do you need to keep a persistent trace of the commits you integrated from `OriginalRepo` ? one blunt way to "replay the content" without keeping this information is : `git diff C D > diff.patch; git apply diff.patch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First—and this is important-*the commit hashes did not change.*  The modified repository has *all-new commits*.  The new commits are just different commits.  The old commits still exist: those are the ones they have in their repository (and you will, at some point, have again in yours).

In general, Git identifies commits by their hash ID.  In a fundamental sense, the hash ID *is* the commit.  Two Gits decide whether they have the same commits by comparing *just the hash IDs*.

This is what makes history rewriting "bad".  A new repository, with all-new commits, is no longer compatible with an old repository.  The history in a repository *is* the set of commits in the repository.  So your history and their history are now completely disjoint.

> What would be the best way to get "D" into MyRepo, without losing history or "X"? (assume that both "X" and "D" are actually a range of commits, and contain merge commits as well)

To get commit `D` literally, you must have your Git call up their Git and have them list out their commit hash IDs for your Git, and then have your Git pick up their commit.  When `D` is a range of commits, you have to pick up the entire range.  The easiest way to do this, by far, is to just have your Git pick up every one of their commits, so that you have all of your commits *plus* all of their commits.  Instead of:

> OriginalRepo: `A  -- B --  C  -- D`
>
> MyRepo:     `A# -- B# -- C# -- X`

you will have:

```
A  -- B --  C  -- D   <-- originalrepo/main

A# -- B# -- C# -- X   <-- main
```

in your repo, for instance.  You now have both sets of commits, so you have both histories.  History is nothing but commits after all.  Your branch name(s), such as `main` or `master`, find the *last* commit(s) in your repository.  The commits themselves point backwards to earlier commits, so that `X` points back to `C#`, which points back to `B#`, and so on.  Meanwhile, your *remote-tracking names*, such as `originalrepo/main`, point to the *last* commit(s) that you got from their repository (now in your repository too).  This lets your Git find `D` easily; `D` points back to `C`, which points back to `B`, and so on.

No part of any existing commit *can* ever change.  That's why, when rewriting history in your repository earlier, your Git had to make *new* commits, with new and different hash IDs.  Their Git and your Git (and every Git in the world) all agree that your new, rewritten commits get those new hash IDs—this was true even before you did the rewrites<sup>1</sup>—and that the originals get the original commit hash IDs.

This `git fetch` trick is simple and easy.  You have commit `D` in your repo, now.  But that's not really what you meant and want, is it?  You actually want commit `D` to somehow *join up* with your commit `X`.  Well ... that's possible, but harder: you will have to decide how you'd like to have this come about, and what, if anything, you plan to do with all of this in the future.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is why Git hash IDs are so big and ugly: we have to pre-allocate every hash ID for every commit that will ever exist in the future, and reserve it to that commit.  This is a sort of [fools' errand](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fool%27s%20errand), so we don't actually do it in advance, we just do it as the commit data and hash IDs show up.  But commit hash IDs are determined algorithmically based on the content, using a cryptographic hash.  The [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) tells us that this concept *will* fail someday; the size and efficacy of the hash pushes that *someday* into the future.  The bigger and better the hash function, the further off is the [Day Of Reckoning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/day%20of%20reckoning), when Git stops working.

More precisely, Git doesn't exactly *stop working* (you can still use your own files just fine).  It just stops *talking to some other Git* because they've both used the same hash ID for a different internal object.  You can no longer fetch or push: we need a new hash function.  That day has not yet arrived for SHA-1, and Git is already moving to SHA-256 to push the day further down the road again.

---

#### How to deal with rewritten histories

Because what Git cares about are *commits*, as identified by their hash IDs, you really have just a few options:

- Undo the rewrite entirely
- Maintain parallel but separate histories
- Join the rewrite to the original

All three of these options are terrible, each in a different way.  The "undo the rewrite" method will have the best *outcome*, but is the hardest to do, usually by far.  The "maintain parallel but separate histories"—sort of a software apartheid—means lots of extra work in the future, but at least that work is relatively amortized: you just copy their `D` commit(s) to new `D#` commit(s) that add on to *your* history, and then, as they make new commits, you keep on copying them.  The "join" method means running `git merge` with `--allow-unrelated-histories`,<sup>2</sup> resolving conflicts—there are almost certainly going to be some, perhaps many—and then making a merge commit, or multiple merge commits.  After that, though, you'll be able to use Git to merge new commits *they* make, relatively easily; the terrible-ness is mainly the up-front work (like the "undo history rewrite" version) plus the fact that now you're dragging around a duplicated early history.

---

<sup>2</sup>Allowing unrelated histories *was* the default and only option, until Git 2.9.  It turned out that this was causing too many causal Git users too much trouble, I guess, so they changed it to be forbidden by default, with an option to allow it.

---

#### How to undo the rewrite

Given the relatively simple drawing, with each `A-B-C-D` representing a *single* commit, this would be pretty easy.  You'd just match up your `A#`—what I usually call `A'`—to their `A` and so on.  That leaves you with one single commit `X` whose parent is `C#`.  To undo the rewrite, you just:

- get all their commits (`git fetch`);
- create a new branch name that selects existing commit `C`;
- use `git cherry-pick` to copy your single commit `X` to a new commit `X'`;
- ditch your commits entirely, in favor of this new history that ends at `X'`; and
- get every other Git repository that *has* `X` to switch to using `X'` instead of `X`, and with that, the `A-B-C-X'` sequence.

For a repository over on GitHub that you control, you'd need `git push --force` to accomplish the last step.  Other users that have cloned that repository—including anyone who forked it, since forking is just a clone with features added—will then have to update *their* repositories as well, and switch to the "un-rewritten" history.

Since `X` is not just a single commit, you'll need multiple cherry-pick operations.  The `git rebase` command is generally the one to use here, since it operates by doing repeated cherry-picking.  However, any internal branch-and-merge operations require *repeating* the merges, rather than *copying* them, so this can be painful (depending on how difficult the merges were originally).  The `rerere` subsystem, and the contributed retrain script, can help here.

#### How to maintain parallel histories

(Start, as always, with the `git fetch` to pick up their commits.)

Use `git cherry-pick` to copy their commits.  That's really all there is to it.  You generally don't want rebase as it does a branch name change at the end, and you want to avoid that part.  You *can* do the rebase from a detached HEAD starting point, or make some sacrificial branch names that you can delete after the rebase finishes.  Otherwise this is much the same as the undo option: we've just changed the set of commits to copy; instead of copying `X`, you're copying `D`.

#### Merging the histories

(Start, as always, with the `git fetch` to pick up their commits.)

This is mostly a matter of one-time pain in terms of coming up with the merge result.  Having run `git fetch`, you now have the history I drew:

```
A  -- B --  C  -- D   <-- originalrepo/main

A# -- B# -- C# -- X   <-- main
```

While on `main`, you run `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories originalrepo/main` to kick off the merging process.  This probably fails with lots of conflicts.  You then spend hours or days resolving the conflicts, producing the correct merge result, and commit the result:

```
A---B--C---D   <-- originalrepo/main
            \
A#-B#-C#--X--M   <-- main
```

New commits you make, and new commits they make, now have a common ancestor, namely commit `D`:

```
A---B--C---D--E   <-- originalrepo/main
            \
A#-B#-C#--X--M--F   <-- main
```

The history goes `F-M-(D and X)` from your commit `F`, and `E-D` from their commit `E`, so commit `D` is on both branches and is the merge base.  For this *future* merge, Git will compare the snapshot in `D` to those in both `E` and `F`, and combine the work to make a new merge commit.

Note that your repository and any clones now carries around both histories; theirs carries around only the original history.